# OO Approach For Hardware Communication... Possible Singleton?

Tags: c++, singleton, static-members

I am working on a project where I need to talk to a particular box over UDP.  There will only ever be one box connected to the system at any given time.  The connection should last the entire duration of the program.

I have written a class that works (yay!) in providing the necessary data to the hardware.  However, my main problem is that now I have to account for the fact that someone (a programmer down the road who will more than likely just ignore all my very neat comments ;) ) may create more than one instance of this class.  This will more than likely result in some hilarious and rather amusing crash where the hardware in question is wondering why it is receiving data from two sockets on the same machine.  More troublesome is the fact that creating the object actually spawns a thread that periodically sends updates.  So you can imagine if my imaginary future programmer does something like create a linked list of these objects (after all, this is C++ and we have the ability to do such things) the CPU might not be very happy after a while.

As a result, I turn to you... the more experienced people of SO who have seen such issues in the past.  I have debated creating a singleton to handle all of this, but some of my readings lead me to believe that this might not be the way to go.  There is a TON of information regarding them on the internet, and it's almost like asking a highly sensitive political question based on the responses I've seen.

An alternative I've developed that will preserve as much code as possible is to just use a static bool to keep track if there is an active thread passing data to the hardware.  However, I suspect my approach can lead to race conditions in the case where I have competing threads attempting to access the class at the same time.  Here's what I have thus far:

```
// in MyClass.cpp:
static bool running_ = false;  // declared in the class in the .h, but defined here
MyClass::MyClass() {
  // various initialization stuff you don't care about goes here
  if (pthread_create(mythread_, NULL, MyThreadFunc, this) != 0) {
    // error
  }
  else {
    // no error
  }
}

static void* MyClass::MyThreadFunc(void* args) {
  MyClass myclass = static_cast<MyClass>(args);
  // now I have access to all the stuff in MyClass
  // do various checks here to make sure I can talk to the box
  if (!running_) {
    running_ = true;
    // open a connection
    while (!terminate) {  // terminate is a flag set to true in the destructor
      // update the hardware via UDP
    }
    // close the socket
    running_ = false;
  }
}
```

While I certainly note that this will check for only one instance being active, there is still the possibility that two concurrent threads will access the !running_ check at the same time and therefore both open the connection.

As a result, I'm wondering what my options are here?  Do I implement a singleton?  Is there a way I can get the static variable to work?  Alternatively, do I just comment about this issue and hope that the next programmer understands to not open two instances to talk to the hardware?

As always, thanks for the help!

Edited to add:

I just had another idea pop into my mind... what if the static bool was a static lock instead?  That way, I could set the lock and then just have subsequent instances attempt to get the lock and if they failed, just return a zombie class...  Just a thought...

Comment: Forgot to add:  the OO approach in this case is actually very handy.  The user of the class does not need to know anything about the hardware which they are sending updates, they just need to provide the data.  Everything else is totally automated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right, asking about singleton is likely to start a flamewar, that will not make you any wiser. You better make up your mind yourself. It's not that hard really if you are aware of the primary principles.

For your case I'd skip that whole branch as irrelevant, as your post is motivated by FEAR. Fear from a speculative issue. So let me just advise you on that: relax.  You can't fight idiots. As soon as you invent some fool-proof schema, the universe evolves and will produce a better idiot that will go around it. Not worth the effort.   Leave the idiot problem to the management and HR, to keep them employed elsewhere.

Your task is to provide working solution and proper documentation on how to use it (ideally with tests and examples too).  If you document usage to create just a single instance of your stuff, and doing the listed init and teardown steps, you can just expext that as followed -- or if not it be the next guy's problem.

Most of the real life grief comes NOT from dismissing dox, but that dox not present or is inaccurate.  So just do that part properly.

Once done, certainly nothing forbids you to ass a few static or runtime asserts on preconditions: it's not hard to count your class' instances and assert it will not go over 1.

Comment: Very well said.  I think all I was really looking for was a way to tell the programmer at run time that something was a miss.  That is, simply having a static counter and checking it periodically and printing some console output should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

What if you have two instances of the hardware itself? [I know you say it will only be one - but I've been there, done that on the aspect of "It's only ever going to be one!! Oh, <swearword>, now we need to use two..."].

Of course, your `if(running_)` is a race-condition. You really should use some sort of atomic type, so that you don't get two attempts to start the class at once. That also won't stop someone from trying to start two instances of the overall program.

Returning a zombie class seems like a BAD solution - throwing an exception, returning an error value, or some such would be a much better choice.

Would it be possible to have "the other side" control the number of connections? In other words, if a second instance tries to communicate, it gets an error back from the hardware that receives the message "Sorry, already have a connection"?

Sorry if this isn't really "an answer".

Comment: Trust me, I thought about the possibility of two pieces of hardware and for this use case, it doesn't make sense.  There will never be another piece of hardware that I will need to talk to of this type.  Also, excuse the confusion regarding the zombie class... since I am spawning the thread in the constructor, there is an error code that will be returned when the caller attempts to pass data to the object (and therefore the hardware) in the event that construction did not go as intended.

Answer (score 0):

First, I do not think you can really protect anything from this imaginary future developer if he's so much into breaking your code. Comments/doc should do the trick. If he misses them, the hardware (or the code) will likely crash, and he will notice. Moreover, if he as a good reason to reuse your class (like connecting to some other hardwares of the same kind), you do not want to block him with nasty hidden tricks.

This said, for your example, I would consider using an `atomic<bool>` to avoid any concurrency issue, and use the compare_exchange member function instead of `if(!running) running = true`:

```
static std::atomic<bool> running;
...
bool expected = false;
if(running.compare_exchange_strong(expected, true)) {
    ...
```